# Python interact with key and value like PHP's foreach?

Tags: php, python, for-loop

On PHP I can simple do:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // do something here
}
```

Ok, I know that I could:

```
for value in arr:
    # do something here
```

but I haven't a way for know what's current key in array, in php foreach $key is current key of $array and $value is current item in $array, so my question is: exits a simple way to do this on python ?

PS: in PHP foreach ($array as $key => $value) work with associative and non-associative arrays, then I want a way that work with lists and dicts in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lists:

```
for i, value in enumerate(arr):
```

For dicts:

```
for key, value in dic.items():
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.

- If you have anything that supports iteration in Python, you can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index at the same time as the next value:

  ```
  for index, value in enumerate(l):
      # pass
  ```
- If you have a dictionary, you can use the [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method to iterate on each `(key, value)` pair:

  ```
  for key, value in d.items():
      # pass
  ```